# Node.js, Socket.io multi-user application - storing user sessions?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a Node.js/Express application to handle (potentially) up to thousands of concurrent users. They will enter information (stored in DynamoDB) and then be split amongst different rooms to interact. I'll use Socket.io to capture and emit actions users take in those rooms (e.g. chatting).

**Problem**

I am not sure the best way to track users as they move through the app and login/logout. We can't store their session data (e.g. room_id, user_settings) on the server, esp when the server crashes.

Two ideas I have that I could use some advice on:

1. Store and retrieve session data from DynamoDB directly. This seems to have high overhead hitting the db so often.
2. Use an in-memory cache like Redis, and flush to DynamoDB when writing. We need data to persist in case of a server crash. Not sure if this works for thousands of users.

I am pretty new to DynamoDB and never used Redis before, so any advice would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is the way to go. It's installation is extremely simple, and there are packages for user session, especially if you use passport, for example [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio). It will take the authentication data and use the `sessionStore` to store the session somewhere.

You don't really need that plugin in order to make it work - you can always have your own middleware in which you save the session to some store. The options I can think of, that are fast enough, are

1. Redis
2. File Storage

File storage means you save sessions as files on the server, so that you minimize reading/writing time, by simply reading a file, and not making db queries, which get expensive over time. Each file has it's unique ID so query is pretty fast. The downside here is that it's hard to maintain - you get tons of folders and files and stuff like that

Redis, on the other hand, is build especially for those kind of things. It's a in-memory storage with the option to save data locally (which means you can restore it if the Redis server dies at some point). It is extremely fast and efficient, because it's in memory. The good thing is that it's a separate process and you don't have to care about memory management - you can configure it to use specific amount and it will handle all the information in a way that you have best performance (old data saved and out of memory when memory is not enough).

So my advice is not to worry that much about the unknown - Redis is pretty simple and you'll get used to it in a few hours (or days at most).